# Digital output protection against accidental contact with 230V AC

Tags: mains, 555, protection

I plan to build a "Wire Tracer" device to identify mystery wires around the house. I found [this](https://www.hobbielektronika.hu/forum/getfile.php?id=223587) schematic, which uses a NE556 based tone generator and a contact-less receiver. Hopefully it should work something like this [product](https://www.extech.com/products/TG20).

All manufacturers warn against using such a device on mains powered wires. I am aware of this precaution and **never plan** to allow such a connection. I do own a "Voltage tester" [stick](https://www.kvelektro.cz/zkousecka-elektroplast-sn-4-vadaska-p1168962) with proper safety rating and I will test all wires first. Sometimes, though, stuff happens. Somebody elsewhere might flip a light switch or a breaker, blasting my circuit with 230V AC. This opens an interesting design question.

**How do I make my device blow up reasonably safely?**

Requirements

- Prevent fire or explosion
- Do not limit the functionality too much

Bonus goals

- Decrease the risk of shock while (dis)connecting the probes to/from live wires
- Protect the circuit from blowing up at all

So far I came up with this circuit, see this [falstad simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWK0BMkDMkBskAskBOLLdXAdlwA50QFJbb6EBTAWjDACh9cQV9wOPpUqD69MKjLIU0mGASkCIsgWwEKlMKIBmAQwA2AZ2acATrTAo+-S9ZQIsUZJDKcAbnZDp0ThFb5HZ3sFelxoJHCkcQjOAHcvHydcMCckqA8QKm9fLNFU8XBGHNF6dGgwFIQCFCxFBEoNAhoYBHi8nKdKMtzITnQ6EHYnLFts0d4JJF9IJFYBBxiUdFl4NfXrABVmAFsAB2YzPQAXAFczUwsB6wLhfKEezgATLNSxbwQboWsn5n1TgzHZ4fazpa7vH5-PQAoF7EDdd4I9IQCT9MhMAIoWz+L4SYLmLy3FJOW4SNDtYnvSkcax9Cw48ABXBYXg05z+PqpazM1lMt5syH-QGsAzMF4o5wwSBcBIM25ygJ9IzwiRCW6k5z6YymZXqmoQsi0opakztLG8MGfToZBK3dJI3qcLmvElCSn8eiC6HC0UvPExOAoAnugSU9ISNbtcHpMOOhLZW4I0ntW6yXHWvoAD1eolUWRIIAIkXA9AA8u5DgYAPZ6J4AHTrADsAJaNp7NgDGJyrZk42dwKz4YBozJCyRLIAAys2AOaNwx92jVPgDEBYDh8FlZCcEABqdaMACMTsdDgBPBstxunszzgyXi5GZtGY56Rsd0zZxw0TBIarTSBRFZegADkAFEEEcRd0DAaQrAgdAyHyRDtzAegPyOHZOwPBAAHVLziZsLgPR9n2OHtuGWbwNECaiR0NDJcCo2Cfy+AgsjzLMVx-ZRvDISJpVQpxS1OY49lEg89jMKtTw7Y5myrRtFwHUEaMcASwkEKdZzvA8Z2YRtDm7Xts1XdACHY4cgMgbktIAQUPU4nwrA8nMOFM1U8iR9T6JiaCxaZ-JQCAqHEDzVQkMhXTC20oveMB9QS2kU0S-U0HyFBSjNQDwEymxWQeM0BFTWxk1tIRkTi8MUyq3Iku8LAsttfVfFEdLvDwG0+ByzBeHNDNFxY7xGiHZJtFQ9C9EPUVL3Ig9qy7U9L1bA89APOJDAMRdIPY3ACAgdcIE+TS0MLfcjxPc9luvQ5dKbUiXzfD9BqHaQB24iaV0gc67IAYUvHY9FbIxF2WCRKg6yygmAtdMB2OyD0bKssLuxtJAQABrOyAAFFn3JtWxvMxTj2Y4Dy7PZoEvHQ3MXGi0JJBNVxhvQOw7ZtfmvQwAaBxsjEvDtFNfOTFxICRMDXLBLOZT7BcbQy5J54HBqosHwEUPgZZhowAAsezJpt2bMDtTmbIFTLIODKAtfbwEoN6JwAES4UziECC0EQcB3TsdoMgA) here.

[image: My circuit so far]

I saw this [eevblog video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUhnGp5vh60) about multi-meter protection. My circuit is different in a few ways. I can tolerate voltage drop on the output, so I can afford to use D1 in series. It's easier to block +330V than short it out via a MOV. The D2 will limit the external -330V voltage to about -1V, which will prevent excessive current flowing from the NE556. Also, better than using a MOV. Is that a correct assumption?

**Fuse**

I'd go for a fuse with "sand" in it. The interrupting capacity is better (1500A@250V AC), compared to glass+air ones, although the smallest value I can get locally is 630mA nominal. According to [datasheet](https://www.gme.cz/data/attachments/dsh.633-247.1.pdf) and simulation, it blows within the first half-sine.

**Diodes**

The 1N4007 are [rated](https://www.gme.cz/data/attachments/dsh.220-002.1.pdf) 1A, 1000V. Surge rating is 30A single half-sine, or 40 half-sines at 10A (this should be my case).

**Limiting resistor**

33R 5W cemented [wire resistor](https://www.gme.cz/data/attachments/dsh.114-030.1.pdf). It should limit the fault current to ~ 10 A. Will it survive? The simulation shows 2.5 kW for a few milliseconds. Higher resistance would mean less fault current/power, but would also decrease output capability of the device. The original circuit drawing uses 100 R, mine has 153R total which seems acceptable. Any suggestions here?

**PTC Thermistor**

I'm at loss here. In theory, this works as a resettable fuse. But is it fast enough? I'm OK with just replacing fuses, if something goes wrong. The PTC in a steady-state would mean continued 230V presence inside the device and a heat producing part inside. Is that a good idea? Do PTC have an I^2t rating as fuses do? Why does the multi-meter in the video use PTC instead of a fuse on the Voltage ranges?

**What other protection method/device can be (reasonably easily) implemented, without being an overkill?**

Comment: How high output impedance can you tolerate? How much capacitive loading can you tolerate?

Comment: @winny I don't really know. The original circuit seems to limit the output to ~ 100mA, probably against short circuit of the NE556. I think that much current is not really needed for proper function, but know nearly nothing about antennas/radio. I still want the receiver to pick up the wire inside a wall, if possible.

Comment: I see. I ask because the higher your can go with a fixed resistor in series, the easier it will be to build a protection for it. The more capacitance you can allow, the more "stuff" you can add in parallel to help the situation. If I where you, I would try to estimate these two parameters and then play around with probably two anti parallel Zener diodes or bi-directional TVS in parallel with your generator and then PTC or fuse in series in a simulator. Fuse behavior isn't easily simulated, but you can measure the I^2t integral easily and say when your fuse would have blown.

Comment: Sand-filled fuses are normally quite slow - you won't get anywhere near 1.5kA through it if you have a current limiting resistor.  You might be better off with a quick blow (F type) fuse, provided it's breaking capacity is above the maximum fault current you are going to see.

Comment: Can you go for a 0.7u capacitor in series? It acts as a 100 ohm resistor for your test signal (2.2KHz), while acting as a 3.7k resistor for mains frequency (60Hz (worst case frequency) ) You only have to deal with short inrush transients.

Comment: @winny Can you please explain the advantage of TVS (or Zeners) over simple D1 and D2? The intended output levels are 0-9V, so anti-parallel Zeners would clip it too low (?), to about +/- of their forward voltage (0.4V). Back to back Zeners would clip to +/- the U_Zn, let's say +/- 9V. The D2 should clip to -1V (sounds best to me), and keep anything above +0V. Where am I mistaken?

Comment: @Ferrybig Great idea, that might avoid a lot of energy going into the device. I can try that on a safe piece of wiring, if the device still works as intended.

Comment: @akwky Sorry, I ment anti-series Zeners.